# Response.Write Unknown Syntax

Tags: asp.net

I've put my hand on an old piece of code. Unfortunatly I have to use and change it. This is where I'm stuck.

```
<%If (rs.Fields.Item("xxx").Value) Then Response.Write("CHECKED") : Response.Write("")%>
```

I can't figure how this works. I can't understand the last part 
`: Response.Write("")%>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of colons is a way to put multiple statements on the same line in VB and VBScript, but in this Context:

```
: Response.Write("")%>
```

It just kind of serves the purpose of an ELSE statement to ensure that the script always returns a string, but with twice the effort.

Which this would also do:

```
<%If (rs.Fields.Item("xxx").Value) Then Response.Write("CHECKED") Else Response.Write("")%>
```

If you don't plan to add anything to the second part, you should be able to leave it as:

```
<%If (rs.Fields.Item("xxx").Value) Then Response.Write("CHECKED")%>
```

If you want to pick up the original line of programming you could go nuts and do something like this:

```
<%
Response.Write("<input type='checkbox' name='") : _
Response.Write(rs.Fields.Item("xxx").Name) : _
Response.Write("' ") : _
If (rs.Fields.Item("xxx").Value) Then Response.Write(" CHECKED ") : _
Response.Write("/>")
%>
```

Added syntactically correct underscores to avoid the horizontal scroll AND keep it on ONE line ;)

Of course, that's pretty silly, but..

Comment: "In VB style languages, including VBScript, the colon is an end of statement token. It allows you to place several statements on the same line." Found this in another topic. Your answer was kind of right, it helped me, thanks.

Comment: I've just seen your edit.« If you don't plan to add anything to the second part, you should be able to leave it as:
`<%If (rs.Fields.Item("xxx").Value) Then Response.Write("CHECKED")%>`» It worked perfectly. Aaaand I don't think i'll go nuts this time :) But i'll keep it in mind, just in case